# IE loads same css on one page all the time wrong

Tags: internet-explorer

IE loads same css to all page but on one page it shows CSS WRONG! ALL THE TIME.
when you click on other pages it loads same css and it's fine! i can't figure out why it shows it wrong! when i try to inspect CSS throe browsers (ff, chrome, IE) they show identical style, eaven IE shows same styles and values, but it displays wrong everthing

it's like he knowledges CSS, but doesn't care about it - AND ONLY FOR ONE PAGE

IT'S SO FRUSTRATING

Comment: It helps if you tell us the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem! it was DOCTYPE! It was written with mistakes